# Change WooCommerce recipient for admin emails

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way to change the recipient email address for all WooCommerce emails that normally go to the site administrator?

The reason for doing this is a separation of roles. The site administrator deals with security alerts, new registrations, password resets, and general site duties. We have another user that is responsible for the online store. All WooCommerce "admin" emails should go to this other person, not the email address specified in Settings --> General.

Ideally, this would be setup in the user profile or WooCommerce settings. I don't have an issue hard-coding the email address in some hook or filter.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without editing core WooCommerce files, and that is not recommended as that would be overwritten next update.

The admin email seams to fetched like this `get_option( 'admin_email' )` everywhere and there is not filter manipulate this.

The best solution might be to ask for a filter ([on their GitHub](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues)).

Comment: I was afraid of this and think you might be right.  I'll post the idea/issue and see where it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This should be possible:

- In the WooCommerce section on the dashboard, there is a setting option
- In that there is an Emails tab.
- In the Email Sender Options section, change/add the ""From" Email Address" to the other users emails address.
- Save the changed made

Comment: This does only effect the from address in the email that is sent to customers, not the notification emails to site admin.